# Grey ''fluffy' dust mixed with 'salt'

Tags: floor

We moved in here a year ago. Since then we have been trying to get rid of problem with grey 'dust' mixed with 'salt'. This covers everything, the floor, the surfaces etc. No matter how often we clean it up the next day it's the same. We cannot find the source. The floor is laminate planks with some tiles in the kitchen area.

Comment: Can you please post a photo

Comment: Most likely this is from the HVAC system.  Have you changed filter/s?  Do you have a filter. Do you open windows? Where in the world are you located? More info and pics will get you better answers.

Comment: Do not have a HVAC system. We are located in Ireland. Open doors and window everyday